# Debug a Node.js app running on android (termux) with --inspect

Tags: android, node.js, termux

I have a Node.js app, which I want to run on my android phone via Termux. So far, I've got everything running. But when I normally run this app on my computer, I run it with the `--inspect=10000` flag, so that I can debug it using Chrome DevTools.

Now my question would be, what do I need to do, to do the same but on my phone?

Running it with the `--inspect` flag gives me this:

```
Debugger listening on ws://127.0.0.1:10000/...
```

Normally, I would just open up `chrome://inspect` and open up Chrome DevTools, configure the host and port, and then Node.js will connect to DevTools. But on my phone, I can't visit `chrome://inspect` and Node.js won't connect to DevTools on my Computer. (Visiting `ws://127.0.0.1:10000` also doesn't work)

Do I need to use another IP than localhost?

Can someone help me?